# How do I find the tangent line at a given point of an accumulation function?

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, tangent-line

so I am having a little trouble with how to start off with this problem. Would I have to find the derivative of G(x) and plugin x=1 first? Any help would be appreciated, thank you!

[image]

Comment: Are you able to compute $G(1)$ and $G'(1)$?

Comment: Well I believe G(1) would just equal 4

Comment: Are you familiar with (part 1 of) the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus?

Comment: Yes I have actually learned about part 1 and 2 of the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus

Comment: $G’(x) = 4+\dfrac{1}{x^4+3}$ by the FTC, and since you found $G(1)$ already, all that’s left is evaluating $G’$ at $x = 1$ and putting it all together.

Comment: I see, so my result was y-4= 17/4 (x-1)